# Count number of 0's in a particular column

Tags: python, pandas

I have a csv which has the following columns

```
Date    isAccepted
```

There are many repeated dates and isAccepted is a boolean value column with 0 and 1. I want to calculate count of 0's for a particular date.

I am trying this :

```
df['Count'] = df.groupby('Date').apply(lambda isAccepted: (isAccepted == 0).sum())
```

But the column returned is NaN. Can anyone tell whats wrong with the code.

Thanks

Comment: @StevenRumbalski I tried `df['Count'] = df.groupby('Date').apply(lambda isAccepted: (isAccepted == 0)).sum()` but it returns the same result.

Comment: @vp7 problem is that when you are iterating using lambda function, it is returning a dataframe, so the type of `isAccepted` is `pandas.core.df`. So if you want to get data out of it use this . `df['Count'] = df.groupby('Date').apply(lambda isAccepted: (isAccepted['isAccepted'] == 0).sum())`

Comment: @ShishirNaresh This still returns a column with NaN values :(

Comment: @vp7  It will return the same o/p, if there exist only one instance of date. For the first time, it will not count and will return `NaN`, if you have multiple instance of date in your dataframe, then it will return 1 for second instance.

Comment: But the output is to be the count of number of 0 for a particular date

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the below code, Hope it will help

```
def countZero(df):
    count = 0
    for accpt in df['isAccepted']:
        if accpt == 0 :
            count += 1
    return count

for date in set(df['Date'].tolist()):

    df['Count'][df['Date'] == date] = countZero(df.groupby('Date').get_group(date))
```

Hope this will help.

Comment: This works.. However, is there a direct way... without even defining a function ?

Comment: @vp7 - sure, there is better solution with `transform`

Answer (score 0):

The problem is when you use groupby('Date'), a new DataFrame is created with 'Date' column now as an index, not anymore a column, so, when your code try to assign values to df['Count'] (a dataframe with original index: 0,1,2,3....n, No 'Dates'), pandas does not find where to put it, so it fills ['Count'] column with NAN. To solve it, try:

DataFrame:

```
data={'Date':['04/09/2019','04/09/2019','04/09/2019','04/09/2019','04/09/2019','04/09/2019','04/09/2019','04/09/2019',
 '05/09/2019','05/09/2019','05/09/2019','05/09/2019','05/09/2019','05/09/2019','06/09/2019','06/09/2019',
 '06/09/2019','06/09/2019','06/09/2019','06/09/2019','06/09/2019'],
      'isAccepted':[0,0,0,1,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0]}      
df=pd.DataFrame(data,columns=['Date','isAccepted'])
```

Create a second DataFrame with the new index resulting of using groupby():

```
df2=df.groupby('Date').sum()
```

Now you can try your code as you wanted, pandas will find where to put the resulting zeros sum, the left and the second term of the code line have now the same index:

```
df2['Count']=df.groupby('Date').apply(lambda column: (column == 0).sum())['isAccepted']
```

Hope this solves your doubt, about why the NAN.

Answer (score 0):

Use [`GroupBy.transform`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.transform.html) if need new column filled by aggregate values:

```
df['Count'] = (df['isAccepted'] == 0).groupby(df['Date']).transform('sum')
```

Similar solution with new helper column with [`DataFrame.assign`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.assign.html):

```
df['Count'] = df.assign(new=df['isAccepted'] == 0).groupby('Date')['new'].transform('sum')
```

And your solution is necessary change with `transform`, but if many groups it should be slow:

```
df['Count'] = df.groupby('Date')['isAccepted'].transform(lambda column: (column == 0).sum())
```